# Custom Validator not firing after CheckBox CheckChanged Event

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, .net-4.5

I'm still trying to understand and find a solution to the following problem :

I have a custom validator :

```
<asp:CustomValidator
  ID="CustomValidator" runat="server"
  OnServerValidate="CustomValidator_ServerValidate"
  Forecolor="Red" Display="dynamic"
  style="margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px"
  ValidationGroup="test">
```

I have a button which call this custom validator :

```
<asp:Button ID="ButtonSave" UseSubmitBehavior="false"
  ValidationGroup="test" Enabled="false" runat="server"
  Text="Valider modifications" OnClick="ButtonSave_Click" 
  CssClass="btn ButtonSave" Width="200px"
  style="margin-right:5px; margin-bottom:10px; margin-top:10px" />
```

and I have also a `CheckBox` with an event:

```
<td class="transparent">
  <asp:CheckBox ID="Type_CheckBoxCancel" 
    Text="Cancel" runat="server" CssClass="EntreeCheckbox"
    TextAlign="Right" OnCheckedChanged="Type_CheckBoxCancel_CheckedChanged" 
    AutoPostBack="true" />
</td>
```

If I click directly on `ButtonSave`, my custom validator is correctly called and I can do all checks. However, when I click on my `CheckBox` then on my button, my custom validator is not called anymore. I don't really understand this behavior.
If someone could propose me a solution, please?

Comment: I test something else : I use a boolean to know if I went to my custom validator event, if not, I use Page.Validate() in my button click event. No validation is done...                                                                                          Also, I checked in firebug, I don't have any error...

Comment: This is really strange. When my CheckBox is checked, my custom validator is not fired anymore on my button click. However, if I remove check on my Checkbox, my custom validator works. So I watched, what I did exactly in my event CheckChanged. Actually, I just disable some controls and enable some controls depending on Check in the Checkbox...I really do not understand this behavior.

Comment: Okay Problem solved................In fact, my custom validator was in a Panel that I disable during when my checkbox is checked....So obviously, my custom validator was also disabled......